# Finding points closest to latitude longitude point using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, proximity

Right now I have a data base with PostGIS. Several of the data sets contain different locations at latitude longitude points. I will be doing several queries based at different latitude longitude points, I need to find the closest locations at each point as well as all the points within a certain number of meters. Right now I was just sorting all the data by closest to the lat/lon point that I was querying, so:

```sql
SELECT 
     rest.station_id
FROM 
     rest
ORDER BY rest.geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint('%(lat)s',' (lon)s')::geometry, 4326)
LIMIT 1
```

where the lat lon variables are what I am querying.

Is there a way to do this better so that I don't have to sort each time I do a query?

Comment: With a spatial index  on gages.geom, the ordering should be very fast. On a side note, you have swapped lat/long when creating the points (it should be longitude first, then latitude)

Answer (score 1):

Based on an example [here](https://learn.crunchydata.com/postgis/qpostgisintro/), you could do something like this:

```
SELECT 
a.station_id,
ST_Distance(a.geom, 'POINT(your_lon your_lat)'::geography) dist 
FROM rest a 
WHERE ST_DWithin(a.geom, 'POINT(your_lon your_lat)'::geography, your_dist_in_meters)
ORDER BY a.geom <-> 'POINT(your_lon your_lat)'::geography;
```